# Borel isomorphism and approximation of Borel space valued function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Kallenberg's *Foundations of modern probability*, he defines a Borel space $(S,\mathcal{S})$ as a measurable space which is Borel isomorphic to a Borel subset $B\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$, ie., there exist a bijection $h:S\rightarrow B$ such that $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are both measurable.

At a later time, when proving a lemma,  $f:(\Omega,\mathcal{A}^\mu,\mu)\rightarrow (S,\mathcal{S})$ to be measurable iff there exists $g:(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)\rightarrow (S,\mathcal{S})$ measurable, such that $f=g$ $\mu$-a.e., where $\mathcal{A}^\mu$ is the $\mu$-completion of $\mathcal{A}$, he assumed $S=[0,1]$ and then approximated $f$ by simple functions $f_n\uparrow f$.

I have question regarding this approximation: In general, only strongly measurable functions (functions with separable images) can be (monotonically) approximated point-wise by simple functions (finite combinations of indicator functions), the fact that $S$ is Borel isomorphic to $B\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$ does not imply $S$ is separable, since the isomorphism $h$ need not be continuous. Is there anything I am missing here? Furthermore, what does Borel isomorphism imply? I guess measurability properties can be preserved, but topological properties in general cannot? Am I completely wrong on something?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure about your Q,,but it is true that measure properties can be preserved without preserving all topological properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every uncountable Borel space is isomorphic to $[0,1]$ with its Borel sets by a result of Kuratowski.So we can always take Borel spaces to be isomorphic to $[0,1]$ (the countable case is usually easy to handle anyways).

So if $S$ is a Borel space and $\phi:S\to[0,1]$ is an isomorphism, then the metric $d:S\times S\to[0,1]$ given by $d(s,s')=|\phi(s)-\phi(s')|$ makes the two spaces also isometric under $\phi$ and therefore homeomorphic. So there is certainly a separable topology on $S$ generating $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the concrete answer. Without knowing Kuratowski Theorem, I now understand Borel space $S$ as to take an arbitrary $S$ with cardinality of continuum, establish an  isomorphism $\phi$ with [0,1], define a sigma algebra on $S$ as generated by $\phi$, and define a metric as you did, which in turn generate a topology, so that $\sigma(\phi)$ is the Borel sigma algebra of the topology. $S$ and [0,1] is  isomorphic in terms of both topological and measure structures, and therefore $S$ is also separable. Did I miss something?

Comment: @user138668 That's exactly it. The point is that you can take the topology that is most convenient to apply the arguments.

Comment: Now I understand the argument: first map $S$ to [0,1], then make use of *topology* on [0,1] to prove a *measurability* claim, then map that claim back to $S$ without the topology. Thank you.